# Explanation wanted: log10 faster than log and log2, but only with O2 and greater

Tags: c++, performance, math, gcc

I need to use a logarithm function in some of my code, but the base doesn't matter. So I set out to pick between `log()`, `log2()`, and `log10()` by performance, provided I found any significant differences. (I will refer to said functions as `ln`, `lb`, and `lg` respectively).

*Why am I fussing about this? Because I will be calling the function as often as 400,000,000 times per iteration of an optimisation algorithm. This is neither optional nor the topic of my question.*

I set up some really basic tests, like so:

```
timespec start, end;
double sum = 0, m;

clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, &start);
for (int n = 1; n < INT_MAX; ++n)
{
    m = n * 10.1;
    sum += log(m);
}
clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, &end);

cout << "ln=";
cout << diff(start, end).tv_sec << ":" << diff(start, end).tv_nsec << endl;

... // likewise for log2 and log10
```

([timespec diff(timespec start, timespec end)](http://www.guyrutenberg.com/2007/09/22/profiling-code-using-clock_gettime/) if you so desire....)

The following results were obtained:

```
GCC v4.6.3

-O0
ln=140:516853107
lb=155:878100147
lg=173:534086352

-O1
ln=133:948317112
lb=144:78885393
lg=163:870021712

-O2
ln=9:108117039
lb=9:134447209
lg=4:87951676

-O3
ln=9:102016996
lb=9:204672042
lg=4:153153558
```

I've looked at the output of compiling with `-S`, but I really don't have a good enough grip on assembler to fully understand the differences. `-S` output: [-O0 -S](http://pastebin.com/u1m5KE1a), [-O3 -S](http://pastebin.com/At3GZEZf)

*Why does `lg` optimise better with O2/O3?*

EDIT: [Source code](http://pastebin.com/2GrdSiFB), note the typo in the third loop, this is the cause of log10 seeming faster (mult. get optimised out). I have accepted the answer I believe is closest, since the question has now been closed, although I learnt a lot from drhirsch's and janneb's answers.

Comment: The output of `-O0 -S` and `-O3 -S` is not accessible (at least for me).

Comment: I get a little confused: what is O0, O1, O2 and O3?
Thanks to @chris, I found: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html if someone reading is also confused

Comment: How many times have you repeated the test?

Comment: @littleadv Somewhere between 5-10 times. It's consistent. Maybe I'll get around to churning out averages over 50 runs later. Maybe not.

Comment: @aldo.roman.nurena Pretty standard knowledge for C programmers.

Comment: @iammilind Really? Weird... I listed it as public, and can access it from both home and work...

Comment: @IskarJarak please paste your complete code so that we can do some tests on it. As well, paste your system features (processor, x64, x86, operative system) so we can compare. I would suggest to compile with -O0 and then test every single flag available on -O2 (as listed on the link above) so we can reach one that optimize that much your code, and then ask why (brute force, not a bad idea for 35 flags. Does anyone know how to flag the compilation programatically?)

Comment: @aldo.roman.nurena It'd be easy enough to iterate through the flags using bash. Might as well use Make too, while you're at it. However, have you considered the possibility that this is caused by some combination of flags? That gives a lot more than 35 options.

Comment: Oh, and I don't have access to my complete code right now, although reconstructing it should be trivially easy for anyone from the above sample plus the link to what I used for the diff function (two more sets of loops and output for each other function, reusing the variables declared above, and the diff function)...

Comment: @IskarJarak, we can hope the best (: and if it is on flags, why not programming it to get all combinations during one night long? haha I'm not on my linux right now. Will try this later unless someone does it before. I hope you publish you code till that so we don't miss even a parentheses
EDIT: do you already know how is this written on bash? i have not compiled with flags from it before

Comment: Put a "cout << "sum=" << sum" line there somewhere, otherwise the compiler will optimize out the log() evaluations at higher optimization levels. At least on my system here (gcc 4.4) with -O2 it changes the timing from 6 to 100 seconds.

Comment: @IskarJarak: You're approaching the problem incorrectly and are jumping to conclusions. using clock is not sufficient for profiling. Use decent profiler instead of clock (gprof or AQTime7). Profiler must be able to provide per-line timings. Your problem is that you assume that bottleneck lies within log function. However int-to-float conversion isn't really fast and can be also a bottleneck. Another thing is that gcc comes with source code that you can read AND log10(INT_MAX) is smaller than log2(INT_MAX), which might mean (just a hunch) that log10 needs less operations than log2 or ln.

Comment: @SigTerm: The fact that less operations are necessary for `log10` may well be the answer to this question.

Comment: @janneb Good point, I should have thought of that. This is probably the cause of the massive drop in runtime. I'll double check tomorrow.

Comment: @SigTerm Thanks for the tip re profiling and for mentioning the gcc source code. Type conversion time doesn't explain `lg` being quicker than `ln` and `lb` though, since they should have the same number of the same kind of casts each.

Comment: @IskarJarak: "since they should have same kind of casts" It means that you don't know if they actually have same kind of casts. Assuming anything is a bad idea - see Murphy's law. Assumptions are less reliable than profiling results.

Comment: @SigTerm Alright, poor wording on my part. They have exactly the same kind and number of casts outside of the log functions.

Comment: I just can't downvote this enough. Janneb is right, the compiler is smarter than you and optimizes away the variable `sum` and the logarithm completely - thats the reason it becomes so fast at `-O2` and higher. Interesting that people manage to _duplicate_ this without doubt. Not suspecting for one second that there maybe is something badly wrong.

Comment: My question was never was was there such a (suspicious) jump in execution time. My question was why does the log10 loop end up being quicker than the other two, when they're exposed to the same optimisations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I noticed some things. If I compile (GCC 4.5.3) your assembler listing `-O3 -S` with `g++ logflt.S -lrt` I can reproduce the behavior. My timings are:

```
ln=6:984160044
lb=6:950842852
lg=3:64288522
```

Then I examined the output with `objdump -SC a.out`. I prefer this to looking into the `.S` files since there are constructs which I do not (yet) understand. The code is not very easy to read, but I find the following:

Before calling `log` or `log2` the argument is converted using

```
400900:       f2 0f 2a c3             cvtsi2sd %ebx,%xmm0
400904:       66 0f 57 c9             xorpd  %xmm1,%xmm1
400908:       f2 0f 59 05 60 04 00    mulsd  0x460(%rip),%xmm0
40090f:       00 
400910:       66 0f 2e c8             ucomisd %xmm0,%xmm1
```

`0x460(%rip)` is a relative adress which is pointing to the hex-value `0000 00000000 33333333 33332440`. This is a 16-byte SSE `double` pair from which only one double is important (code is using scalar SSE). This double is `10.1`. `mulsd` thus performs the multiplication in the C++ line `m = n * 10.1;`.

`log10` is different:

```
400a40:       f2 0f 2a c3             cvtsi2sd %ebx,%xmm0
400a44:       66 0f 57 c9             xorpd  %xmm1,%xmm1
400a48:       66 0f 2e c8             ucomisd %xmm0,%xmm1
```

**I think for the case of `log10` you forgot to perform the multiplication!** So you are just calling the `log10` with the same value again and again ... I would not surprise me if the cpu is clever enough to optimize that.

EDIT: I am now very sure this is the problem, because in your other listing (`-O0 -S`) multiplication is correctly performed - so **please post your code** and let others prove me wrong!

EDIT2: One way GCC *could* get rid of this multiplication is by using the following identity:

```
log(n * 10.1) = log(n) + log(10.1)
```

But in that case `log(10.1)` would have to be computed once and I do not see this the code. I also doubt that GCC would do that for `log10` but not for `log` and `log2`.

Comment: Verdammt, I was beginning to suspect something like that myself, but I can't check it because I'm away from my machine right now (and have been for the last couple of hours =/).

Comment: I was actually lucky to able to answer this question. If the vermin exterminators would not make their routine examination today, I would not have stayed home ;)

Comment: Well, lucky us ;)
Hmm, just noticed your edit. That's pretty weird because I swear they were compiled from the exactly same source code. Can't wait to check the code ASAP, but it's going to be another ten hours or so before I can do so >_<

Comment: OK, I am really looking forward to this :)

Comment: Why downvote? Anything not correct?

Comment: You failed to notice that the code the OP posted doesn't actually call the `log` function (`ucomisd` and a conditional jump directly after it... what may _that_ do?). Step through it with a debugger, and you will see that the code just does 2^31 multliplications. Well, actually you got fooled by the OP - blame him.

Comment: @cschwan Source here: http://pastebin.com/2GrdSiFB
I feel so stupid now - I wrote `log10(n)` instead of `log10(m)`which caused the multiplications to get optimised out of the last loop. Sigh.

Comment: @drhirsch "fooling" entirely unintentional, tvm.

Comment: @IskarJarak I surely hope so :-) (Actually, while reading the janneb's answer the first time, thoughts about you being a troll trying to fool us all briefly crossed my mind - but only for a very short time) I should remember Hanlon's razor and write it down a thousand times. I apologize for being harsh.

Answer (score 6):

This is going to depend on the implementation of the log() functions in the C library, compiler version, hardware architecture, and so on. Anyway, below I'm using GCC 4.4 on x86-64 with glibc 2.11.

Changing the example so that I add a line

```
cout << "sum=" << sum << endl;
```

which prevents the compiler from optimizing away the log() calls, as I mentioned in a comment, I get the following timings (whole seconds only, -O2):

- log: 98s
- log2: 105s
- log10: 120s

These timings seem roughly consistent with the -O0 and -O1 timings in the original post; at higher optimization levels the log evaluations are optimized away, hence the -O2 and -O3 results are so different.

Furthermore, looking at the log example with the "perf" profiler, the top 5 offenders in the report are

```
# Samples: 3259205
#
# Overhead         Command              Shared Object  Symbol
# ........  ..............  .........................  ......
#
    87.96%             log  /lib/libm-2.11.1.so        [.] __ieee754_log
     5.51%             log  /lib/libm-2.11.1.so        [.] __log
     2.88%             log  ./log                      [.] main
     2.84%             log  /lib/libm-2.11.1.so        [.] __isnan
     0.69%             log  ./log                      [.] log@plt
```

Except for main, all the other symbols are related to the log() call. Summing up these, we can conclude that 97% of the total runtime of this example is spent in log().

The implementation of __ieee754_log can be found [here in the glibc git repo](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/ieee754/dbl-64/e_log.c;hb=HEAD). Correspondingly, the other implementations are: [log2](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/ieee754/dbl-64/e_log2.c;hb=HEAD), [log10](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/ieee754/dbl-64/e_log10.c;hb=HEAD). Note that the previous links are to the HEAD versions, for released version see their corresponding branches

Comment: Well, if it just optimizes away the loop, it would still be interesting to know, why the log10 version is double as fast (in his version), even though they should result in complete same code.

Comment: @ChristianRau: I suspect the reason may be that the log10 version in the OP's code is actually a bit different, see the answer by cschwan. What I'm wondering about, actually, is why the compiler optimizes away the log() calls but not the entire loop; if the compiler can see that sum is never used after the loop, certainly it can also see that m is never used?

Comment: @ChristianRau: I disagree. It is completely not interesting to see why a compiler produces slightly different code for a loop in which more than 90% are optimized out. It may depend on to many random variables - exact architecture where the code is executed, compiler version, glibc version, compiler flags, even linking may play a role.

Comment: @drhirsch Yes indeed it depends on many different things, but it is not that the code for those three different versions is any different except for the called function inside the (opetimized out) loop (this we have to believe the OP), so there has to be a definite reason and this reason is interresting, no matter if it makes any difference to you for some higher productivity goal. Compilation depends on many things but it is definitely deterministic and those things don't change in these three versions. The one thing that actually changes and makes the difference is a point of interest.

Comment: @janneb Yes, could be. This would answer my little comment question and shed light on this definitely interesting matter.

Comment: @ChristianRau Ok, I agree it might be mildly interesting :-) See my answer for an explanation why not everything is completely optimized away.

Comment: @ChristianRau And the answer is I'm a muppet, and overlooked a one character typo. Not very interesting at all.

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately the OP failed to show us the original code, he chose to obfuscate the code slightly converting it to assembly.

In the assembly code the OP linked (annotations by me):

```
.L10:
    cvtsi2sd %ebx, %xmm0         // convert i to double
    xorpd    %xmm1, %xmm1        // zero 
    mulsd    .LC0(%rip), %xmm0   // multiply i with 10.1
    ucomisd   %xmm0, %xmm1       // compare with zero
    jae       .L31               // always below, never jump

    addl    $1, %ebx             // i++
    cmpl    $2147483647, %ebx    // end of for loop
    jne     .L10
    ...
.L31:
    call    log10, log2, whatever...  // this point is never reached
```

One can see that the call to `log` is never executed, especially if you step through it with gdb. All the code does are 2<sup>31</sup> multiplications and comparisons of a double.

This also explains the stunning increase of execution speed of the log function by a factor of 30 when compiled with `-O2`, in case anybody found this strange too.

Edit:

```
for (int n = 1; n < INT_MAX; ++n)
{
    m = n * 10.1;
    sum += log(m);
}
```

The compiler isn't able to completely optimize the loops away, because she is not able to prove that the call to `log` will always succeed - it has side effects, if the argument is negative. So she replaces the loop by a comparison with zero - the `log` is only executed, if the result of the multiplication is less or below zero. Which means it is never executed :-)

What stays in the loop is the multiplication and the test if the result might be negative.

An interesting result happens if I add `-ffast-math` to the compiler options, which relieves the compiler from the strict IEEE compliance:

```
ln=0:000000944
lb=0:000000475
lg=0:000000357
```

Comment: FWIW, it turns out that it's enough to use -fno-math-errno, the whole shebang of -ffast-math is not necessary.

Answer (score 3):

You're approaching the problem incorrectly and are jumping to conclusions.

Using clock is not sufficient for profiling. Use decent profiler instead of clock (gprof or AQTime7). Profiler must be able to provide per-line timings. Your problem is that you assume that bottleneck lies within log function. However int-to-float conversion isn't really fast and can be also a bottleneck. Another thing is that gcc comes with source code that you can read.

Now, **assuming** that bottleneck actually lies within log function:

As you're supposed to know, doubles have limited precision - only 15..17 decimal digits. It means that with larger logarithm base, you'll sooner reach situation when you hit precision limit.

I.e. `10^(log10(2^32) + 10^-15) - 2^32` == `9.8895 * 10^-6`, but `2^(log2(2^32) + 10^-15) - 2^32` == `2.977  * 10^-6` and `100^(log100(2^32) + 10^-15) - 2^32` == `0.00001977`, also `log2(INT_MAX) > log10(INT_MAX)` It means that with larger logarithm base, if logarithm function tries to "search" for a proper result, it'll sooner hit situation where modifying predicted result is no longer possible due to rounding off errors. However, this is still just a guess.

There are other ways to calculate logarithm. For example, `log10(x) == ln(x)/ln(10)` if logarithm function were calculating it this way, you would get nearly similar timings.

My recommendation would be to (stop wasting time,) profile your program with something other than clock functions (reinventing the wheel is bad idea, and not using existing profiling tools is reinventing the wheel, plus a good profiler will be able to provide per-line timings from within log function), read gcc source code for log functions(it is available, after all) and assembly output. If you don't understand assembly output, it'll be a good opportunity to learn how to read it.

If it is REALLY important to have faster logarithm function, and algorithmic optimization REALLY isn't possible (if logarithm really is a bottleneck, you could cache results, for example) you could try to find faster algorithm implementation, but if I were you in this case I'd simply try to throw hardware at the problem - by parallelizing the task, for example.

Comment: Contrary to some other compilers, gcc does not ship its own math library. If the OP is using Linux, the log functions would live in glibc.

Comment: @janneb: You know, it really doesn't change much. Both are part of GNU project, and source code is available for both.